# Javascript decrement from 10 then do something when 0

Tags: javascript, function, counter

I have a function that when called will decrease by 1.  It is called when a user reports something.  I want to be able to store this and then when it hits 0, to execute an action.

```
function userReported() {

    console.log('user report ' + add());

    var add = (function () {
          var counter = 10;
          return function () {
            counter -= 1; 
            return counter;

          }

    })();

}
```

Now the problem is I can return the counter so it logs down from 10.  But the issue I have is that I can seem to add an if/else before returning counter as it does not store the variable.

I attempted the following but it doesn't work and I don't know how to return something > store it, and at the same time check its value.  I also tried a while loop but failed too.

```
function userReported() {

    var limit = add;

    if ( limit <= 0 ) {
        console.log('Link does not work!'); 
        }
        else {
            console.log('user report ' + limit);
        }

    var add = (function () {
          var counter = 10;
          return function () {
            counter -= 1; 
            return counter;

          }

    })();


}
```

How do I go about creating a value, increment/decrement said value, then when it reaches a number -> do something?

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, `add` is a function, which means `limit` is a function, so `limit <= 0` doesn't make much sense. Why not `counter <= 0`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate If I do counter <= 0 I always get 'counter is not defined'.  If I replaced var limit = add with var counter = 10;  I always get user report 10 and it never counts down.

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything. It seems like you need to return a function that holds the state in a closure. And each time *that* function is called the count decreases.

Comment: define the `var counter = 10` outside the decrement function.

Comment: Your first example isn't doing what it says it is.  The `add` is a variable holding a function.  The function has not been hoisted as that is not a named function.  Your first example would break at the log statement (if _userReported_ were ever called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically do this with a function that returns a function that captures the counter in a closure. This allows the returned function to maintain state over several calls.

For example:

```js
function createUserReport(limit, cb) {

    console.log('user report initiated' );

    return function () {
        if (limit > 0) {
            console.log("Report filed, current count: ", limit)
            limit--
        } else if (limit == 0) {
            limit--
            cb() // call callback when done
        } 
        // do something below zero?
    }
}

// createUserReport takes a limit and a function to call when finished
// and returns a counter function
let report = createUserReport(10, () => console.log("Reached limit, running done callback"))

// each call to report decrements the limit:
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    report()
}
```

You can of course hard-code the callback functionality and limit number into the function itself rather than passing in arguments.

Comment: Thank you, your answer solves the problem.  So to clarify I needed a callback to access the stored value?

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles, no the callback just lets you customize what happens at the end. You can see it called at `cb()` in the returned function. The stored value is stored in the `limit` argument, which is outside the returned function. The returned function is able to see an manipulate this (but it's not accessible outside the function).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you need to get a report based on an external limit, you could do something like that:

```
var limit = 10;

function remove() {
  limit -= 1;
}

function userReport() {
  if (limit <= 0) {
    console.log("Link does not work!");
  } else {
    remove();
    console.log(`User report: ${limit}`);
  }
}

userReport();
```

If that's what you want, removing the remove function from userReport and taking the limit variable out will make things work

Comment: Yes my question is a bit difficult to explain.  I tried this code but the function does not count down, it perpetually stays at 10.

Comment: Every call to `userReported` will reset the limit to 10. Also the function `add()` is never called.

Comment: Ok, now I understood. Look at the modifications and see if that fits you